# How to write count(*) SQL in DQL, Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

How to get count of rows in database by id?
`SELECT count(*) FROM members;`
Without performance issues. What are  ways to write this query using entityManager? 
I am using `php version 5.6` and `symfony 3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use your EntityRepository 
Add a function in it and write something like this:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('COUNT(e)')
        ->from('AppBundle:Entity', 'e');

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Just saw Gregoire's answer. That will work. However, if you already have the Entity which has the relation, and it's initialized, the below would allow you to get this info without an additional query to the DB.

---

You could use the association and get it from the Collection (see [Working with Associations in the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)

```
class SomeEntity
{
    /**
     * @var Collection|Member[]
     */
    protected $members;

    // other properties

    // PHP >= 7 -> public function countMembers(): int
    public function countMembers()
    {
        return $this->getMembers()->count();
    }

    // PHP >= 7 -> public function getMembers(): Collection
    public function getMembers()
    {
        return $this->members;
    }

    // other getters/setters
}
```

Comment: I am on php 5.6.

Comment: Removed strict types for PHP < 7

Comment: Added strict types function declaration for getters (>= PHP 7) as comments for illustration (someone might need them)